# Calculating a characteristic function two different ways gives contradictory results. Why?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to calculate a characteristic function directly and via the conditional distributions. I get contradictory results:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables defined on the same probability space.

Let the conditional pdf of $X$ given $Y=u$ be

$$h_{X\mid Y=u}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac12,& \text{ if } u=0 \text{ and } 0\le x \le 2\\
1,& \text{ if } u=1 \text{ and } 0\le x \le 1\\
0,& \text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}$$

Also, let $Y=0$ with probability $\frac 12$ and let $Y=1$ with probability $\frac 12$. With this the pdf of $X$ is

$$h(x)=\frac 12 h_{X\mid Y=0}(x)+\frac 12 h_{X\mid Y=1}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac34,& \text{ if } 0\le x \le 1\\
\frac14,& \text{ if } 1\le x \le 2\\
0,& \text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}$$

Now, the characteristic function of $X$ can be calculated

$$\mathbb E\left[e^{iXt}\right]=\frac 34\int_0^1e^{ixt}\ dx+\frac14 \int_1^2e^{ixt} \ dx=\frac 3{4it}\left[e^{it}-1\right]+\frac 1{4it}\left[e^{2it}-e^{it}\right]=$$
$$=\frac3{2t}e^{i\frac t2}\sin\left(\frac t2\right)+\frac1{2t} e^{it}\sin(t) .\tag 1$$

The same characteristic function can be calculated another way. First let's calculate the conditional characteristic functions of $X$ given that $Y=u$.

$$\mathbb E\left[e^{iXt}\mid Y=u\right]=\begin{cases}
\frac12 \int_0^2e^{ixt}\ dx,& \text{ if } u=0\\
\int_0^1 e^{ixt} \ dx ,& \text{ if } u=1.
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
\frac 1{2it}\left[e^{2it}-1\right],& \text{ if } u=0\\
\frac1{it}\left[e^{it}-1\right],& \text{ if } u=1.
\end{cases}=$$
$$=\begin{cases}
\frac 1{t}e^{it}\sin(t),& \text{ if } u=0\\
\frac 2{t}e^{i\frac t2}\sin\left(\frac t2\right),& \text{ if } u=1.
\end{cases}$$

Then 
$$\mathbb E\left[e^{iXt}\right]=\frac12\mathbb E\left[e^{iXt}\mid Y=0\right]+\frac12\mathbb E\left[e^{iXt}\mid Y=1\right]=$$

$$=\frac 1{2t}e^{it}\sin(t)+\frac1{t}e^{i\frac t2}\sin\left(\frac t2\right).\tag 2$$

The two results, $(1)$ and $(2)$ contradict to each other. What the hack am I doing wrong?

(In order to test the logic of the computations, I've determined the expectation of $X$ the two different ways. The results agreed!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first approach I get $$-\frac{i e^{i t} \left(-1+e^{i t}\right)}{4 t}-\frac{3 i \left(-1+e^{i
   t}\right)}{4 t}$$ which after simplification is exactly the same as the result of your second approach. It hence could be that your integrations/simplifications are flawed in the first apparoach.

Answer (score 1):

Your evaluation of the right-hand term of $(1)$ is wrong (even after you corrected the typo). You need to take out $\mathrm e^{3\mathrm it/2}$ and leave $\sin(t/2)$, and then it will be a bit of a mess to show the equality of the two results – perhaps easiest to write $\sin t$ as $2\sin(t/2)\cos(t/2)$ and expand the cosine back into exponentials. The reason it's complicated is that you've basically inserted a spurious intermediate integration limit in part of the $u=0$ track and extracted different factors from the two resulting $\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}$ terms, thus masking the fact that they cancel.

Comment: Thx for the $\mathrm e^{3\mathrm it/2}$ idea (+1). It's simplified lots of things but I am still not done. This may be just my dumbness. But I am already dizzy.